# QStyledItemDelegate reimplementation: color item background when mouse over

Tags: c++, qt, delegates, paint, qstandarditem

My original aim was to feed items (QStandardItem) of a specific column with rich text, therefore I implemented a subclass delegate as suggested.

Everything looked fine except one thing: when I moved the mouse pointer over these items, they were not highlighted at all. (The other items in the row - where the original paint method is used - were highlighted.) Item selection worked fine although. Then I added line

```
if ( optionV4.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver )
```

in which I was able to handle the item text highlight, but I have no idea how to highlight the background too. It is still white. Any ideas?

Here is the relevant code:

```
class MStyledItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT

protected:
    void paint ( QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index ) const;
    QSize sizeHint ( const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index ) const;
};

void MStyledItemDelegate::paint( QPainter* aPainter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& aOption, const QModelIndex& aIndex ) const
{

    // ...

    QStyleOptionViewItemV4 optionV4 = aOption;
    initStyleOption( &optionV4, aIndex );

    QStyle* style = optionV4.widget ? optionV4.widget->style() : QApplication::style();

    QTextDocument doc;
    doc.setHtml( optionV4.text );

    optionV4.text = QString();
    style->drawControl( QStyle::CE_ItemViewItem, &optionV4, aPainter );

    // highlight text
    QAbstractTextDocumentLayout::PaintContext ctx;
    if ( optionV4.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver )
    {
        ctx.palette.setColor( QPalette::Text, Qt::blue );
    }

    // draw
    aPainter->save();

    QRect textRect = style->subElementRect( QStyle::SE_ItemViewItemText, &optionV4 );
    aPainter->translate( textRect.topLeft() );
    aPainter->setClipRect( textRect.translated( - textRect.topLeft() ) );
    doc.documentLayout()->draw( aPainter, ctx );

    aPainter->restore();
}
```

Comment: ctx.palette.setColor (QPalette::Base, Qt::red)

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I tried both Base and Window ColorRoles, but they had no effect.

ctx.palette.setColor( QPalette::Base, Qt::red );
ctx.palette.setColor( QPalette::Window, Qt::yellow );

Comment: you forgot to set optionV4 palette colo. in your if block add optionV4.palette.setColor(QPalette::Base, Qt::red)

Comment: I can't look into my code, but I managed to do the background coloring with `doc.setBackgoundBrush(...)` or something similar as I remember correctly.
But I will try what you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use it with a QTableView, call the method `setMouseTracking(true)`.

Comment: I use it with QTreeView. Mouse tracking is false defaultly, so I tried setMouseTracking(true) as well, getting no difference. But it would be strange, that text highlight worked without mouse tracking, but background highlight did not.

Comment: Have you try set a css with `doc.setDefaultStyleSheet("background-color: #ff0000;")` ?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it yet. But I will check it in the new year, I'm on holiday now.